# C# MVC Post Model and additional data to controller from js

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am working with a custom workflow solution that I am creating.  I would like to create a postback that has the model, and two integer values that represent the action and step that I have completed.  I don't want to add them to the model because they are only used in this one place.  The signature for this postback would be something like this.

```
[HttpPost]
public void ProcessWorkflowAction(EditScreenModelValidation model, int stepActionId, int stepNumber)
{
    //Some work on model and actions
}
```

I would really like to do this through JS because that is currently how I am getting StepActionId and StepId.  Is there a way to package up the model to send through JS?

```
 var modelObj = CreateModelData();
 var postObj = JSON.stringify(modelObj);
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        traditional: true,
        dataType: "json",
        url: "url",
        data: { model: modelObj, stepActionId: stepId, stepNumber: 3 }
        cache: false,
        complete: function (data) {
        }});

CreateModelData = function () {
    var modelObj = {};
    var modelArray = $('#frm').serializeArray()
    $.each(modelArray, function (index, value) {
        assign(modelObj, value.name, value.value);
    })

    return modelObj;
};

function assign(obj, prop, value) {
    if (prop != undefined) {
        if (typeof prop === "string")
            prop = prop.split(".");

        if (prop.length > 1) {
            var e = prop.shift();
            assign(obj[e] =
                     Object.prototype.toString.call(obj[e]) === "[object Object]"
                     ? obj[e]
                     : {},
                   prop,
                   value);
        } else
            obj[prop[0]] = value;
    }
}
```

The model comes back as null in the controller.  I have also tried the following code with the same result.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        traditional: true,
        dataType: "json",
        url: "url",
        data: { model: $('#frm').serializeArray(), stepActionId: stepId, stepNumber: 3 }
        cache: false,
        complete: function (data) {
        }});
```

Comment: you can use ajax to call ProcessWorkflowAction

Comment: Yes, but how do I package up the model into a json object with any data changes that have been made?

Comment: Are you simply asking how to create an object in js and send that as `model` to your controller?

Comment: Yes,  I updated the question to hopefully be a bit more specific in what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: var model = { your data }var data = {
        'model': model,
        'stepActionId': 1,
        'stepNumber': 1
    } and pass data into ajax call

Comment: @Nate...Daniel's comment is right on

Comment: If you have generated you form correctly, you can simply use `var modelObj=$('form').serialize(); modelObj['stepActionId']=stepId; modelObj['stepNumber']=3;` and then in the ajax function `data: modelObj,`. The `DefaultModelBinder` will correctly bind the model and the other 2 parameters of your method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is how I got it to work.  The CreateModelData uses the (frm).serializeArray() method, but I found that if the item was disabled or not on the page, then it didn't create that property.

```
    var modelObj = CreateModelData();

    var postObj = JSON.stringify(modelObj);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        traditional: true,
        dataType: "json",
        url: "url",
        data: { modelString: postObj, stepActionId: stepId, stepNumber: 3 },
        cache: false,
        complete: function (data) {
        }});
});

CreateModelData = function () {
    var modelObj = {};
    var modelArray = $('#frm').serializeArray();
    $.each(modelArray, function (index, value) {
        assign(modelObj, value.name, value.value);
    })

    return modelObj;
};

function assign(obj, prop, value) {
    if (prop != undefined) {
        if (typeof prop === "string")
            prop = prop.split(".");

        if (prop.length > 1) {
            var e = prop.shift();
            assign(obj[e] =
                     Object.prototype.toString.call(obj[e]) === "[object Object]"
                     ? obj[e]
                     : {},
                   prop,
                   value);
        } else
            obj[prop[0]] = value;
    }
}
```

On the controller side, I changed the signature to be all string values like so.

```
[HttpPost]
public void ProcessWorkflow(string modelString, int stepActionId, int stepNumber)
{
}
```

To make the modelString value the actual model object, I did this.

```
using (Stream s = GenerateStreamFromString(json))
{
    DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(modelObj));
    return (modelObj)serializer.ReadObject(s);
}
```

In the end, this worked for me.  All the fields were there and I got no errors.  When i tried to have the first variable in the controller method to be the model object, it always came back as null for me no matter what I did.

Comment: check my answer. With my solution you won't need to change the typed Model to string.

Answer (score 4):

You need to build up the object, assign the properties (make sure it matches any model validation and the field names are the same as your model) and use `JSON.stringify` to make the conversion:

```
 var modelObj = {};
 modelObj.prop1 = $('#txtField1').val();
 modelObj.prop2 = $('#txtField2').val();
 // etc... make sure the properties of this model match EditScreenModelValidation

 var postObj = JSON.stringify(modelObj); // convert object to json

 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    traditional: true,
    dataType: "json",
    url: "/Workflow/Home/ProcessWorkflowAction",
    data: { model: postObj, stepActionId: stepId, stepNumber: 3 }
    cache: false,
    complete: function (data) {
        if (data.responseText.length > 0) {
            var values = $.parseJSON(data.responseText)
            $('#ActionErrors').html(values.message)
        }
        else {
            location.reload();
        }
    }});
```

Comment: I will give this a try and get back to you on how it works.  My model is fairly large as this is system is collecting a lot of data points.  So I will write a piece of js to create the model from the inputs name attribute so that it will automatically handle the deletion or addition of new fields.

Comment: So when I do this, I get null for my model.   I used $('frm').serializeArray() to get all the values in the model.  It has them all, but I still get null.  Any further ideas?

Comment: Does your model have a default/empty constructor? Also, what does your json look like that gets sent?

Comment: My model only has the default constructor.  I verified that the json had all the parameters that I expected and nothing else.

Comment: @Nate - yes, but depending on how the json is formatted... for example, does it start with `model: [` or not, that will affect how your WebAPI method interprets that.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible and pretty easy to do.  MVC is nice about packaging up what you send it.

So if your model looks like:

```
public class TestModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

And your post method looks like:

```
[HttpPost]
public void TestMethod(TestModel model, int num1, int num2)
{
    // Stuff
}
```

Your javascript POST would look like:

```
function doPost(){
    $.post("/Home/TestMethod",
    {
        model: {
            Name: "Joe",
            Age: 29
        },
        num1 : 5,
        num2 : 10
     },
     function (data, status) {
         //Handle status if you decide to return something
     });
}
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

The fastest and easiest way to get all the fields in the Model is to serialize the Form which is bound with Model.

#### Update

The problem that you were receiving null in properties is because `serializeArray()` create key value format json. you just need to get re-build the json from key value to Property value that can be mapped to the model.

```
var modelObj = $('#formId').serializeArray()
                           .reduce(function (a, x) { a[x.name] = x.value; return a; }, {});
```

A little tweak in you ajax call instead of `datatype` use `contentType`. This is another reason you were getting null in controller's model object parameter.

```
         $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "/Account/RegisterSome",
            data: { model: modelobj, id: 3 },
            contentType: 'application/json',
            cache: false,
            complete: function (data) {
            }
        });
```

Comment: Ok, so I did this, and I get null for my model on the controller.  When I debug the js, it looks like all the fields are there correctly.  I also tried adding Json.Stringify(modelObj) to see if that would populate the model, and it didn't.  Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post sample of your view?

Comment: Was in the middle of doing that.  The code is currently what I am working with.

Comment: @Nate I have updated the answer try this now. This will work and no other change required. I have verified it by doing a quick POC.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by removing the JSON.stringify() and just posting my javascript object.